# Can I make Lua wait for an event to finish before executing again?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am using events in Lua I subscribe with:

```
Runtime:addEventListener("balanceChanged", onBalanceChanged)
```

And raise them with

```
Runtime:dispatchEvent({ name = "balanceChanged" })
```

Now in onBalanceChanged, I want to do some animation on the screen that may take a few seconds to finish - but during this time the same event can be dispatched again.

How to I ensure that the onBalanceChanged function is only executed one at a time, aka if it's currently executing, wait for it to finish before carrying on?

Comment: You can see if corona has a way to mask event firing (e.g. call `maskEvent("balanceChanged")`/etc. and it won't fire until `unmaskEvent("balanceChanged")`/etc. is called) but if not you probably need to manually sequence that with a lock/etc. of some kind.

Comment: Easy way is have a flag say isAnimOver = false. Then before playing animation check whether the flag is set to false, then play the animation simultaneously set the flag to true. Once the animation s over again set the to false.

Answer (score 0):

ex:

```
local isAnimOver = false

function playAnimation()
  if not isAnimover then
     isAnimOver = true

   -- here play the animation 
  --- Once the animation is over then set the flag to 
  isAnimOver = false
  end 
end
```